# How to Create Text Link in Pure XML Without setMovementMethod()?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I want to link to an out-of-app resource on Android with pure HTML in XML without having to call setMovementMethod.  Setting:

```
        <TextView
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/the_message"
             android:autoLink="web"
             android:linksClickable="true" />
```

Does not work.  Help?

Comment: did you find solution?